# Raspberry Pi can't install mysql or nginx

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

Not sure what the issue is.  But when I

```
sudo apt-get install mysql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mysql
```

I get the same error when I try and install nginx.
Have a raspberry pi 3 b+. `sudo apt-cache search nginx` turns up no results

Comment: What do you have inside your /etc/apt/sources.list ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already tried doing the `update`, but nothing happened.  Then I ran `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and now I am getting nginx and mysql-server.

Answer (score 0):

First you should update package list:

`sudo apt-get update`

then:

`sudo apt-get install mysql-server nginx`